# Execute script before specific wireless disconnect?

Tags: wireless, mount, cifs, nas

I have a laptop and NAS. What I want to do is to mount my NAS only when my wireless is connected, and umount it at wireless disconnected.

I have written both scripts I wat to run- they check the name of the connection and connect or disconnect. I have added the connect and disconnect scripts to to /etc/network/if-up.d and /etc/network/if-down.d.

The script which starts at if-up works correctly, the other one not- it will simply not umount. I thing the script executes when the wireless is already disconnected.

I want a way to run the script pre-disconnecting the wireless.

I used to do this with wicd in Kubuntu 11.04, but it seems too buggy now.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you understand that your system can't figure out when will a wireless connection drop unless you press a button that tells it.

From what I have seen you just want to get rid of the mount when the network goes down, for that you can use

> umount -l /mnt/folder

Its considered dangerous by many since it will unmount a file system that might still be in use but since your network is already down I don't see much of a problem.

Comment: I try to run  `umount -l /media/MyBookLive` Unfortunately, the command will not work as expected - the system will still hang waiting for the NAS to respond... I will have to swallow wicd bugs probably